# Likelihood of correctly guessing at least M out of N cards in drawn from D decks

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

Let's say there's a game where person A shuffles a number (**D**) of decks into a single large deck, and then draws a set number of cards (**N**) from that deck, face down onto a table.

Person B is then supposed to guess which cards are on the table. The order doesn't matter, but the same card may appear more than once when several decks are shuffled together.

Is there a formula to calculate the odds of person B guessing at least **M** cards correctly, that works for any number of decks and cards drawn?

Definitions:

- **Deck** - A normal 52 card deck, four suits of thirteen cards each.
- **D** - The number of decks combined and shuffled. At least one, no upper limit.
- **N** - Number of cards drawn from the combined decks.  At least one, limited to total number of cards available in decks.
- **M** - Lowest number of correct guesses for a win.  At least 1, at most N.

Example:
Person A combines two decks for a total of 104 cards and shuffles them.  He then draws 5 random cards: "A♠, 4♥, K♦, 8♣ and K♦".

What are the odds that person B guesses at least four of those cards correctly? If person B guesses "K♦" once that counts as *one* correct, she has to guess "K♦" twice in order to get them both.

Comment: Should we assume that player $B$ guesses efficiently and never repeats a guess?  It is more likely to have no repeats than a specific repeat.  If so, you can assume without loss of generality that player $B$ guesses the cards $A\clubsuit,2\clubsuit,3\clubsuit,\dots$, having guessed $N$ different cards assuming that $N\leq 52$.  In the case that $N>52$ then continue the pattern again.

Comment: Hm, no, assuming I understand your question correctly.  I think it might be a better idea to assume a person is only allowed to make one guess, but that there are a very large number of independent guessers (who are unaware of the guesses of other players).
With that assumption, how many players would you need to expect someone to win the game.

Comment: This is certainly not my domain though, so I'm unsure of nomenclature and may very well have interpreted your questions incorrectly, or explained myself incorrectly for that matter.

Comment: alkanen: I *think* @JMoravitz means that it is better strategy for Player B not to repeat a *card rank/suit* in their one guess of the *set* drawn by Player A.